# compare data from one database table to another database table in python, sqlite3 more efficiently

Tags: python, sqlite

***Edit: The end goal is to essentially sync both databases which are updated by different software on both ends.***

Here's the setup, the main database (**dbOne.db**) and the new database (**dbTwo.db**) both contain the same table (**myTable**) and have the same Columns (**account_id**, **guid**, **state**, **last_update**).

The goal is to iterate through **dbOne** and search **dbTwo** for **account_id** and **guid**, if no results are found then I'm modifying the **guid** with some regex and searching again before moving on to the next result, if I find any information then I'm updating it based on the **last_update**.

Here is what the code essentially looks like.

```
for m in dbOne.execute("SELECT account_id, guid, state, last_update From myTable"):
    n = dbTwo.execute("SELECT account_id, guid, state, last_update From myTable WHERE account_id={dbOne.account_id} AND guid={dbOne.guid}'")
    # I would check to see if there is any results from n using n.fetchone()
        if n.fetchone() is None:
            # I modify the guid using regex
            n = dbTwo.execute("SELECT account_id, guid, state, last_update From myTable WHERE account_id={dbOne.account_id} AND guid={dbOne.guid_modified}'")
            if n.fetchone() is None:
                continue
        # Compare dbOne.last_update with dbTwo.last_update then do stuff
```

Just to note that this isn't the actual code, I've just tried to simplify it as much as possible to give a better understanding of what I've done, the code I have works but I feel like there could be a better way to do this.

I've very little experience with SQL but through my searches, I've discovered things like ATTACH and JOIN as well as an IIF or CASE statements that can be used, so I had this idea of throwing it into a query somehow and doing something like `IF guid does not match anything in the database then try {guid_modified}, else continue.` if there is a match then it would return the **account_id**, **guid**, **state**, and **last_update** from both databases, then I would compare **last_update** from both to find the newer date and then update **state** in one of the databases.

One thing I don't know, is if it would be possible to modify the guid within the query since regex strips the guid then uses an api to get some information in order to modify it, so I think I would have to recall the query again regardless, but I was just hoping for a second opinion as I am still in the midst of learning python but I want to ensure my code is as efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You explained how you're achieving the goal, but what is the goal? Does there need to be two separate databases? This would be much more efficient with two tables in one database.

Comment: @Schwern sorry, the goal is to sync the data between two databases that will be in two different locations, I have no control over the database itself as it's run by different software but I want to sync them so if something changes on one it also updates on the other.

Comment: Syncing is hard. Instead of two sides updating two SQLite databases and then syncing, could you have both sides talk to one SQL server? If not, you can simplify and speed things up by searching for both the GUID and the modified GUID at once: `where guid = dbOne_guid or guid = dbOne_guid_modified`. It might also be faster to only search for records which have been updated since your last sync.

Comment: @Schwern - I just had a thought.. what if dumped both tables into a temporary database **table_a**, **table_b** processed them and whatever one I updated would then be sent back to their parent database? would that be better?

Comment: @Schwern sorry only seeing your other comment. "It might also be faster to only search for records which have been updated since your last sync" - that will be a periodical thing, but to start I'd need to do my first sync which would require running through the entire database. But I think you're right about running through both versions of the guid, it would prevent needing a second loop. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: A single temp database at least allows you to this efficiently with a join, if you index them, but it adds even more complexity and risk to the process. While you're syncing the copies more changes will be added to the original tables. When you're done syncing the copies the copies need to be synced with the originals, or you need to lock the original tables while you're syncing introducing a performance problem. The simplest and most robust approach is to use a single database server. Or push updates into a shared queue which both services can read to update their own databases.

Comment: @Schwern syncing would only happen once every night or manually if needed, but in both cases, the databases would be locked or the software temporarily stopped to prevent issues. 

"The simplest and most robust approach is to use a single database server. Or push updates into a shared queue which both services can read to update their own databases" - I never thought about this, this would be the best way, I'll have to look into this more, thank you again for the help.

Comment: Maybe look into using the [session extension](https://www.sqlite.org/sessionintro.html)

Comment: @Shawn man that sounds perfect, thank you!